Consulta como hacer un DLL en C#
Buenos días le comento estoy actualizando un programa en winform  C#, solo algunas funciones adicionales al sistema y pensé en hacer DLL con las funciones para serlo mas rápido la codificación, por ende,  requiero hacer varios DLL pero en VS Studio 2022, lo hice en VS Studio 2018 o 2019,  no encuentro como hacerlo con Framework 4.8, todo lo que he pillado es con framework .net 8, como lo puedo hacer, ya que el sistema no me permite referenciarlo entre si, es decir un sistema hecho en framework 4.8 con DLL con .net 8.0, y no quiero codificarlo desde 0.
Gracias

vs studio es la ide.. lo que vos tenes que instalar son los sdk de los frameworks que queres usar.. de ahi tu problema.. instala el framework 4.8 y fin de tus problemas...

baje el instalador me dice que ya esta en el equipo, que puede ser

Cambia el framework destino cuando creas la dll..

El proyecto que buscas se llama "Biblioteca de clases (.NET Framework)". Todas las plantillas que tengan entre paréntesis .NET Framework se refieren a .NET 4.8 y anterior

Si elijo cualquier con (.NET Framework) y cuando lo refiero al proyecto original me dice que son incompatible entre Framework 4.8 con .Net 8, la pregunta es como hacer que el proyecto original con los DLL pero echo con Framewok 4.8 en VS Studio 2022, esa es la consulta, como se hace. Gracias

Ya lo encontré gracias por su ideas, era una Biblioteca de clases (.NET Framework)" lo que me ha dicho Yussef
